# Dynamically control the number of buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm working with WPF recently. Now, i'm facing a problem.

I have a button "ADD", every time click on this will add a new row with some contents. Those contents are shown below-

```
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"  ></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding City}" Margin="10,10" Height="20" ></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}" Margin="10,10" Height="20" ></TextBox>
                    <Button Content="M1" Margin="10,10" Height="20"/>
                    <Button Content="M2" Margin="10,10" Height="20"/>
                    <Button Content="M3" Margin="10,10" Height="20"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
```

Here, at the end there are three buttons M1,M2,M3. But, I don't need this all three buttons every time. I may need only M1 or only M2 or only M3 or M1,M2 etc.

How can I do this in c#? 
Actually i don't even know, am i in the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend looking into the MVVM design pattern when working with WPF

That said, I would bind my XAML to an `ObservableCollection<SomeObject>`, and clicking the `AddButton` would add a new `SomeObject` to the `ObservableCollection`. This would make the UI automatically add the new row when the collection gets updated, and `SomeObject` could have properties for `IsM1Visible`, `IsM2Visible`, and `IsM3Visible` which determines which buttons are visible.

For example,

Class `SomeObject` would have

```
string Name;
string City;
int Age;
int Count;
bool IsM1Visible;
bool IsM2Visible;
bool IsM3Visible;
```

The XAML would look something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"  ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding City}" Margin="10,10" Height="20" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}" Margin="10,10" Height="20" ></TextBox>
                <Button Content="M1" Visibility="{Binding IsM1Visible, Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"/>
                <Button Content="M2" Visibility="{Binding IsM2Visible, Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"/>
                <Button Content="M3" Visibility="{Binding IsM3Visible, Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the Add Button's Click event would look something like this:

```
void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = new SomeItem
        {
            Name = "Something",
            City = "Something",
            Age = 30,
            Count = 2,
            IsM1Visible = true,
            IsM2Visible = false,
            IsM3Visible = true
        };

    SomeCollection.Add(newItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use DataBinding if the amount of buttons is dependent on the size of a list/collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Ms}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command={Binding ThingToDoWhenClickedCommand}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This will generate exactly the amount of buttons that is in the Ms collection/List that is in the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the buttons through your code-behind files and put an if structure around the buttons to determine what button should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVVM?

If so then this is easy. Just create a ButtonViewModel object that represents one of your buttons and expose an ObservableCollection of them from your main ViewModel.

In your view just have a ListView, or just an ItemsControl bound to the collection, and a DataTemplate that turns your ButtonViewModel into a button.

When the user clicks the Add button, add a new ButtonViewModel to your collection and the view will update itself to match.

Answer (score 0):

First, let create a view model for a row. In that model you will have 3 bool properties, IsButton1Visible, IsButton2Visible, IsButton3Visible, or something like that with all properties you need to do binding on your row.
Second, your scenario is that when you click Add, new row will be added. So you have a list of Row_View_Model.  On AddCommand, you will at a new Row_View_Model into the list. Here you have full control on what button you want to show.